# Modification of CCA plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan

How to colour or change the "species" shape, according to "Use" factor.

```
library(vegan)
data(dune, dune.env)
mod = cca(dune ~ A1 + Moisture + Manure,dune.env)
library(ggvegan)
autoplot(mod)
```

So I would like to distinguish quickly between "Use" factors, it would also be nice to put an ordihull around these.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the species points by `Use` as this is a sample-level variable. If you want to change the site points, that you'll need to do yourself using the `fortify` method.

This will get you so far:

```
fmod <- fortify(mod)
size <- 1.8
ggplot(fmod, aes(x = Dim1, y = Dim2)) +
  geom_point(data = subset(fmod, Score == "species"),
             aes(colour = "species"), size = size) +
  geom_point(data = cbind(subset(fmod, Score == "sites"), Use = dune.env$Use),
             aes(shape = Use, colour = "sites"), size = size) +
  scale_colour_brewer("Score", palette = "Set1") +
  coord_fixed() +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

This gets you:

[image]

You'll need to look at the code for `ggvegan:::autoplot.cca` to see how the biplot arrows and centroids are handled and plotted.

Comment: Thanks Gavin, I have tweaked code to get the biplot arrows and labels;
`geom_text(data = subset(fmod, Score == "biplot"), aes(x=Dim1,y=Dim2,label=Label), size=2) + xlab("CCA1") + ylab("CCA2") + geom_segment(data = subset(fmod, Score == "biplot"), aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = Dim1, yend = Dim2), arrow = arrow(length = unit(1/2, 'picas')), colour = "red")`

Comment: You wouldn't believe how difficult these processes are in some external softwares, just to re-iterate the power of r platform, especially when conducting data analysis on datasets which are constantly changing!

Answer (score 0):

Final answer below, thanks to assistance from Gavin;

```
   fmod <- fortify(mod)
    size <- 1.8
    ggplot(fmod, aes(x = Dim1, y = Dim2)) +
      geom_point(data = subset(fmod, Score == "species"),
                 aes(colour = "species"), size = size) +
      geom_point(data = cbind(subset(fmod, Score == "sites"), Use = dune.env$Use),
                 aes(shape = Use, colour = "sites"), size = size) +
      scale_colour_brewer("Score", palette = "Set1") +
      coord_fixed() +
      theme(legend.position = "top")+
      geom_text(data = subset(fmod, Score == "biplot"), 
              aes(x=Dim1,y=Dim2,label=Label), size=2) + xlab("CCA1") + ylab("CCA2") +
      geom_segment(data = subset(fmod, Score == "biplot"),
                   aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = Dim1, yend = Dim2), arrow = arrow(length = unit(1/2, 'picas')), colour = "red")
```

Comment: That's not quite right for the biplot arrows, at least not if you are trying to be consistent with **vegan**/**ggvegan**. There, as long as the biplot arrows are not the only thing we're plotting, the arrows are scaled to fill the region. Look at `ggvegan:::autoplot.cca` and you'll see a call to `arrowMul` which does this. Given your code, you'll probably want to do that to the biplot scores in `fmod` and then the plotting code remains the same/unaltered from what you have.